# Finite element method and Galerkin projection example

Tags: matrices, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, finite-element-method

The first picture is the formulas for the finite element method I learnt. And the second picture is an example in the textbook. I am wondering where do $2/3$ and 8/3 come from? Is it because 4*$h/6$ and 4*$2h/3$ (the first two formulas in the first picture)? And why there are only 3 elements per line? And why are the first $c_j$ and the last one per line are the same? How to calculate that? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What text are you using?

Comment: Numerical Analysis 2e by Sauer

Comment: Your first two questions can be answered by taking a closer look at $(7.30)$.

Comment: I mean where does that formula come from? Can we use that in every BVP?

Comment: It looks like the equation 7.26-7.29 are called B-spline relations and is applicable in this case. That's also where they get the values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Okay. I think I have two questions: 1. How do they get the number? 2/3, 8/3 etc. Is it the number in the formula times 4? 2. Why is the number before $c_i$ and $c_{i+2}$ are the same? such as c0 and c2 in the first line and c1 and c3 in the second line.

Comment: I believe so, since there is a 4 in their application of 7.25. I am uncertain of the second question since it seems to have to do with the formula also.